# How do I shift my pandas dataframe structure?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Suppose I have a data that look like this:

```
item   | date  | status

A        12-01    E
A        12-02    E
A        12-03    B
A        12-04    B
B        12-01    E
B        12-02    B
B        12-03    S
B        12-04    S
C        12-03    E
C        12-04    E
```

Now what I want to do is to make the data as below:

```
item   | 12-01  | 12-02 | 12-03 | 12-04

A        E          E       B       B
B        E          B       S       S
C                           E       E
```

So in summary, I want to make each row as an item's history.
I heard that this is called 'pivot', but I'm not sure about doing this "easily" by pandas.

Can anyone help me with this?!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df.pivot(index='item', columns='date', values='status')
print (df)
date 12-01 12-02 12-03 12-04
item                        
A        E     E     B     B
B        E     B     S     S
C     None  None     E     E
```

If duplicates in `item` with `date` use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with some aggregate function like `','.join` or `sum`:

```
print (df)
   item   date status
0     A  12-01      E <-duplicates A, 12-01
1     A  12-01      C <-duplicates A, 12-01
2     A  12-02      E
3     A  12-03      B
4     A  12-04      B
5     B  12-01      E
6     B  12-02      B
7     B  12-03      S
8     B  12-04      S
9     C  12-03      E
10    C  12-04      E

df = df.pivot_table(index='item', columns='date', values='status', aggfunc=','.join)
print (df)
date 12-01 12-02 12-03 12-04
item                        
A      E,C     E     B     B
B        E     B     S     S
C     None  None     E     E
```